# How to make the size of a point in ggplot2 inversely proportional to its numeric value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using **ggplot2** to visualize three variables from a dataset such as this:

```
data = data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 10, replace=TRUE), y = sample(1:10, 10, replace=TRUE), Rank = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

with example code here:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(size = Rank))
```

However, I would like the size of a point to be *inversely* proportional to its rank, so that points with a rank close to '1' are large, and for this to be displayed correctly in the legend.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `1/Rank`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(size = 1/Rank))
```

Comment: Just beat me to it ;), plus one. Maybe you could also divide your data by `max(Rank)` to normalize to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  This gives the correct display, but now the legend doesn't reflect the rankings themselves.  This seems like a straightforward issue but I'm new to ggplot2 and couldn't find a quick fix for it.

Comment: If this answers your question for you satisfactorily, Tim, you might consider accepting it by clicking on the 'check' mark underneath the vote total to the left of the answer.